# HEVC not playing in Moto G4 Plus while streaming from server

Tags: php, android, mp4, hevc, moto

I'm `developing` an `android` app, in which I want to play HEVC formatted MP4 video in `android` devices. The source MP4 video is uploaded to `server` and I'm using `PHP` to stream video from server to `android` devices. The video is playing in Moto E2, RedMi note 4 but not in Android G4 plus. I have checked the decoders list. Moto G4 has `decoder` to `decode` HEVC MP4 video as in Moto E2. I'm using default android `MediaPlayer` and `VideoView` class. But when I use `Exoplayer` the streaming works. Can anyone help me in understanding
the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Code from the following link works for me [MediaCodecDemo](https://github.com/cedricfung/MediaCodecDemo) or we can use googlesample [MediaCodec Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BasicMediaDecoder)